# How to multiply multiple lists together in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, math, scipy

I have been looking at producing a multiplication function to be used in a method called Conflation. The method can be found in the following article ([An Optimal Method for Consolidating Data from Different Experiments](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1005/1005.4978.pdf)). The Conflation equation can be found below:

[image]

I know that 2 lists can be multiplied together using the following codes and functions:

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(lista,listb)]
list(map(operator.mul, lista, listb))
np.multiply(lista,listb)
ab = [lista[i]*listb[i] for i in range(len(lista))]
lista = [1,2,3,4]
listb = [2,3,4,5]
ab = []                        #Create empty list
for i in range(0, len(lista)):
     ab.append(lista[i]*listb[i])      #Adds each element to the list
```

But looking into more than 2 lists, I keep on having either error message regarding size-1 arrays or the code looks at the first variables from each distribution, however, for the rest of the loop it keeps on printing the same values, it does not go to the next values in the lists and Conflated distribution is a single variable. See the following code with a portion of the output and error message:

1st Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for c,dist in enumerate(dists):
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

A portion of the output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Denom:  3.95931575736075e-96
Incoming Array: 1
final: 2.1463837356630605e-32
final: 5.0231307782193034e-48
final: 3.266239495519432e-61
final: 2.187514996217005e-81
final: 1.979657878680375e-97
Conflated PDF:  0.049999999999999996
```

2nd Code:

```
import winsound
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain
import scipy.stats as st
from glob import glob
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import pywt
import peakutils
import scipy
import os
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, rfft, rfftfreq, dst, idst, dct, idct
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, find_peaks_cwt, argrelextrema, welch, lfilter, butter, savgol_filter, medfilt, freqz, filtfilt
from pylab import *
import glob
import sys
import re
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis, median_absolute_deviation
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, kendalltau, spearmanr, ppcc_max
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_abs_change as mac
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_change as mc
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_second_derivative_central as msdc
from pyAudioAnalysis.ShortTermFeatures import energy as stEnergy
import pymannkendall as mk_test
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad,simps, quad_vec, nquad

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    i=0
    # p_pdf=np.ones(np.array(dists)[0].shape)
    dist_size = np.array(dists).shape
    print('Incoming Array:', dists)
    print('Incoming Array Size:', dist_size[1])
    print('Full Incoming Array Size:', dist_size)
    print('Number of Incoming Array Size:', dist_size[0])
    # print('Incoming Product Array:', p_pdf)
    # print('Incoming Product Array Size:', np.array(p_pdf).shape)
    if dist_size[0]==2:
        p_pdf=dists[0]*dists[1]
        print('final:', p_pdf)
        results=dists[0]*dists[1]
        i+=1
    elif dist_size[0]>2:
        results=dists[0]*dists[1]
        for i in range(2, dist_size[0]):
            p_pdf=results*dists[i]
            print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
    # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1))
# dist_2 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5))
# dist_3 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6))
# dist_4 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3))
# dist_5 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
# print('distribution list: \n', dists)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

Error Message:

```
in line 79, in conflate_pdf:
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The way I see it, the first code is the approach that I want and the error in the second code is because the integration part requires one a scalar number. How can I fix both codes in order to obtain the following output?

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
    for dist in dists:
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
    print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
    denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
    print('Denom: ', denom)
    conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dists=[stats.norm(2,1), stats.norm(2.5,1.5), stats.norm(2.2,1.6), stats.norm(2.4,1.3), stats.norm(2.7,1.5)]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

graph=conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is a small portion of the desired output:

```
Incoming Array: 1
final: 0.15352177537004433
final: 0.034348669264845304
final: 0.006519131844904635
final: 0.0015040030811035296
final: 0.0003607258742065213
Incoming Array: 1
final: 0.042345986284209325
final: 0.006294747321619583
final: 0.0007651214249593444
final: 9.805307029794648e-05
final: 1.668121592516301e-05
Denom:  0.0029066671327537714
Incoming Array: 1
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.41991991e-32 2.72804284e-32 ... 6.41980576e-15
 5.92770938e-15 5.47278628e-15]
final: [4.75178372e-48 5.66328097e-48 6.74864868e-48 ... 7.03075979e-21
 6.27970218e-21 5.60806584e-21]
final: [2.80912097e-61 3.51131870e-61 4.38823989e-61 ... 1.32670185e-26
 1.14952951e-26 9.95834610e-27]
final: [1.51005552e-81 2.03116529e-81 2.73144352e-81 ... 1.76466623e-34
 1.46198598e-34 1.21092834e-34]
final: [1.09076800e-97 1.55234627e-97 2.20861552e-97 ... 3.72095218e-40
 2.98464396e-40 2.39335035e-40]
Conflated PDF:  [3.75264162e-95 5.34063998e-95 7.59844666e-95 ... 1.28014389e-37
 1.02682689e-37 8.23400219e-38]
```

Desired Plot:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I managed to update the update code based on @MaxPierini, but, I can not get desired plot of conflated distribution. See the following code and output:

Code:

```
import winsound
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain
import scipy.stats as st
from glob import glob
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import pywt
import peakutils
import scipy
import os
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, rfft, rfftfreq, dst, idst, dct, idct
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, find_peaks_cwt, argrelextrema, welch, lfilter, butter, savgol_filter, medfilt, freqz, filtfilt
from pylab import *
import glob
import sys
import re
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis, median_absolute_deviation
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, kendalltau, spearmanr, ppcc_max
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_abs_change as mac
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_change as mc
from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import mean_second_derivative_central as msdc
from pyAudioAnalysis.ShortTermFeatures import energy as stEnergy
import pymannkendall as mk_test
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad,simps, quad_vec, nquad

def prod_pdf(x,dists):
    p_pdf=np.ones(np.array(dists)[0].shape)
    # p_pdf=1
    print('Incoming Array:', dists)
    print('Incoming Array Size:', np.array(dists)[1].shape)
    print('Incoming Product Array:', p_pdf)
    print('Incoming Product Array Size:', np.array(p_pdf).shape)
    for c,dist in enumerate(dists):
        p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]
        print('final:', p_pdf)
    return p_pdf

# def conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
#     print('Input product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
#     denom = quad(prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
#     # denom = simps(prod_pdf)
#     # denom = nquad(func=(prod_pdf), ranges=([lb, ub]), args=(dists,))[0]
#     print('Denom: ', denom)
#     conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
#     print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
#     return conflated_pdf

# use computed PDFs and matrix
def conflate_pdf(x,dists):
    # numerator (product)
    # num = np.array(dists).prod(axis=0)
    num = prod_pdf(x,dists)
    print('Input product pdf: ', num)
    # conflation = prod_pdf(x,dists)
    # normalize (integral)
    conflated_pdf = num / num.sum()
    print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
    return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

dist_1 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
# dist_1 /= dist_1.sum()
dist_2 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
# dist_2 /= dist_2.sum()
dist_3 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
# dist_3 /= dist_3.sum()
dist_4 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
# dist_4 /= dist_4.sum()
dist_5 = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)
# dist_5 /= dist_5.sum()

# dist_1 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1))
# dist_2 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5))
# dist_3 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6))
# dist_4 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3))
# dist_5 = list(st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("Conflated PDF")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(domain, dist_1, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
# print('distribution list: \n', dists)
# graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists,lb,ub)
graph=conflate_pdf(domain, dists)

plt.plot(domain,graph, 'm', label='Conflated Dist.')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Incoming Array: [array([2.14638374e-32, 2.41991991e-32, 2.72804284e-32, ...,
       6.41980576e-15, 5.92770938e-15, 5.47278628e-15]), array([2.21385563e-16, 2.34027620e-16, 2.47380598e-16, ...,
       1.09516706e-06, 1.05938091e-06, 1.02471859e-06]), array([5.91171893e-14, 6.20014921e-14, 6.50239789e-14, ...,
       1.88699641e-06, 1.83054781e-06, 1.77571847e-06]), array([5.37554463e-21, 5.78462242e-21, 6.22446263e-21, ...,
       1.33011515e-08, 1.27181248e-08, 1.21599343e-08]), array([7.22336360e-17, 7.64263883e-17, 8.08589121e-17, ...,
       2.10858694e-06, 2.04149972e-06, 1.97645911e-06])]
Incoming Array Size: (2000,)
Incoming Product Array: [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
Incoming Product Array Size: (2000,)
final: [2.14638374e-32 2.14638374e-32 2.14638374e-32 ... 2.14638374e-32
 2.14638374e-32 2.14638374e-32]
final: [5.02313078e-48 5.02313078e-48 5.02313078e-48 ... 5.02313078e-48
 5.02313078e-48 5.02313078e-48]
final: [3.2662395e-61 3.2662395e-61 3.2662395e-61 ... 3.2662395e-61 3.2662395e-61
 3.2662395e-61]
final: [2.187515e-81 2.187515e-81 2.187515e-81 ... 2.187515e-81 2.187515e-81
 2.187515e-81]
final: [1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97 ... 1.97965788e-97
 1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97]
Input product pdf:  [1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97 ... 1.97965788e-97
 1.97965788e-97 1.97965788e-97]
Conflated PDF:  [0.0005 0.0005 0.0005 ... 0.0005 0.0005 0.0005]
```

Plot:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I implemented the code from the answer (provided by *@MaxPierini*) and it seems to work, also, I managed to sort out the problem with `quad` it seems if I changed the `quad` into `fixed_quad` and normalise the pdf list. I will get the same result. Here is the following code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer, normalize, StandardScaler
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps, quad_vec, nquad, cumulative_trapezoid
from scipy.integrate import romberg, trapezoid, simpson, romb
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad, quadrature, quad_explain
from scipy import stats
import time

def user_prod_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
for dist in dists:
print('Incoming Distribution Array:', dist.pdf(x))
p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
return p_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('Input product pdf: ', user_prod_pdf(x,dists))
denom = quad(user_prod_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,))[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
conflated_pdf=user_prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

def user_conflate_pdf_2(pdfs):
"""
Compute conflation of given pdfs.

[ARGS]
- pdfs: PDFs numpy array of shape (n, x)
where n is the number of PDFs
and x is the variable space.

[RETURN]
A 1d-array of normalized conflated PDF.
"""
# conflate
conflation = np.array(pdfs).prod(axis=0)
# normalize
conflation /= conflation.sum()
return conflation

def my_product_pdf(x,dists):
p_list=[]
p_pdf=1
print('Incoming Array:', p_pdf)
list_full_size=np.array(dists).shape
print('Full list size: ', list_full_size)
print('list size: ', list_full_size[0])
for x in range(list_full_size[1]):
p_pdf=1
for y in range(list_full_size[0]):
p_pdf=float(p_pdf)*dists[y][x]
print('Product value: ', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF:', p_pdf)
p_list.append(p_pdf)
print('final Product PDF:', p_pdf)
print('Product PDF list: ', p_list)
# return p_pdf
return p_list
# return np.array(p_list)

def my_conflate_pdf(x,dists,lb,ub):
print('\n')
# print('product pdf: ', prod_pdf(x,dists))
print('product pdf: ', my_product_pdf(x,dists))
denom = fixed_quad(my_product_pdf, lb, ub, args=(dists,), n=1)[0]
print('Denom: ', denom)
# conflated_pdf=prod_pdf(x,dists)/denom
conflated_pdf=my_product_pdf(x,dists)/denom
# conflated_pdf=[i / j for i,j in zip(my_product_pdf(x,dists), denom)]
print('Conflated PDF: ', conflated_pdf)
return conflated_pdf

lb=-10
ub=10
domain=np.arange(lb,ub,.01)

# dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
# dist_2 = st.norm(2.5,1.5)
# dist_3 = st.norm(2.2,1.6)
# dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
# dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
# dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.5,1.5)
# dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.2,1.6)
# dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
# dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

dist_1 = st.norm(2,1)
dist_2 = st.norm(4,2)
dist_3 = st.norm(7,4)
dist_4 = st.norm(2.4,1.3)
dist_5 = st.norm(2.7,1.5)

dist_1_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2,1)
dist_2_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 4,2)
dist_3_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 7,4)
dist_4_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.4,1.3)
dist_5_pdf = st.norm.pdf(domain, 2.7,1.5)

# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()

# User:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# User 2:
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("User Conflated PDF 2")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
user_graph=user_conflate_pdf_2(dists)
print('Final User Conflated PDF 2 : ', user_graph)

# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()

plt.plot(domain, user_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# My Code:
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("domain")
plt.ylabel("pdf")
plt.title("My Conflated PDF Code")
plt.plot(domain, dist_1_pdf, 'r', label='Dist. 1')
plt.plot(domain, dist_2_pdf, 'g', label='Dist. 2')
plt.plot(domain, dist_3_pdf, 'b', label='Dist. 3')
plt.plot(domain, dist_4_pdf, 'y', label='Dist. 4')
plt.plot(domain, dist_5_pdf, 'c', label='Dist. 5')

dists=[dist_1_pdf, dist_2_pdf, dist_3_pdf, dist_4_pdf, dist_5_pdf]
my_graph=my_conflate_pdf(domain,dists,lb,ub)
print('Final Conflated PDF: ', my_graph)

my_graph /= np.array(my_graph).sum()

# my_graph = inverse_normalise(my_graph)

plt.plot(domain, my_graph, 'm', label='Conflated PDF')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Conflated PDF:
print('User Conflated PDF: ', user_graph)
print('My Conflated PDF: ', np.array(my_graph))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question here, I understand that I would need to normalise the PDF lists. But, say I did not normalise the PDF, how can I modify my conflation code to get the following plot?

[image]

To get the plot above and my conflated code:

```
# user_graph /= user_graph.sum()
# dist_1_pdf /= dist_1_pdf.sum()
# dist_2_pdf /= dist_2_pdf.sum()
# dist_3_pdf /= dist_3_pdf.sum()
# dist_4_pdf /= dist_4_pdf.sum()
# dist_5_pdf /= dist_5_pdf.sum()
```

My conflated code plot with no normalisation:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I won't read all of that code. Do you mean this? `np.prod([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], axis=0) == array([15, 48])`

Comment: @timgeb Something like that, but, you can just concentrate on 1st code and desired code. How can I reach to desired output?

Comment: In function `prod_pdf` why isn't argument x used?

Comment: @DarrylG well, I removed the x argument but I keep on getting error. So, I left it.

Comment: Please, try to reproduce the error you're facing with as minimal code as possible, so you/we can isolate the problem and find a solution.

Comment: @MaxPierini For the second code, the error lies within the product PDF function. First code there is no error, but, I can not produce the same results in desired code, output and plot.

Comment: Which one? There are two `prod_pdf`, the first with `p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]` (where you aren't using argument `x`) and the second with `p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)` (where you're using the argument `x`)

Comment: @MaxPierini I want the `prod_pdf`, from the first with `p_pdf=p_pdf*dist[c]` to give out the same results as in the second with `p_pdf=p_pdf*dist.pdf(x)`

Comment: Ahhh now it's clear, I answered, hope it can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230549/discussion-between-wdpad159-and-max-pierini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `prod_pdf` you are using computed PDFs while in the first you were using defined distributions. So, in the second `prod_pdf` you already have the PDF. Thus, in the for loop you simply need to do `p_pdf = p_pdf * pdf`

From the paper you linked, we know that "For discrete input distributions, the analogous definition of conflation is the normalized product of the probability mass functions". So you need not only to take the product of PDFs but also to normalize it. Thus, rewriting the equation for a discrete distribution, we get

[image]

where `F` is the number of distributions we need to conflate and `N` is the length of the discrete variable `x`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# use defined distributions
def prod_pdf_1(x, dists):
    num = 1
    for dist in dists:
        num *= dist.pdf(x)
    den = 0
    for i in x:
        _mul = 1
        for dist in dists:
            _mul *= dist.pdf(i)
        den += _mul
    return num / den

# use computed PDFs
def prod_pdf_2(pdfs):
    num = 1
    for pdf in pdfs:
        num *= pdf
    den = 0
    for i in range(len(num)):
        _mul = 1
        for pdf in pdfs:
            _mul *= pdf[i]
        den += _mul
    return num / den
```

The first definition uses distributions, the second uses PDFs.

Now let's define distributions and PDFs.

```
# define x variable
x = np.linspace(-2.5, 7.5, 100)

# define distributions
dists = [
    sps.norm(2.0, 1.0),
    sps.norm(2.5, 1.5),
    sps.norm(2.2, 1.6),
    sps.norm(2.4, 1.3),
    sps.norm(2.7, 1.5),
]

# compute PDFs
pdfs = [
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.0, 1.0),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.5, 1.5),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.2, 1.6),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.4, 1.3),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.7, 1.5),
]
```

We can now compute the conflation and plot. Note that we do not need to normalize the conflated distribution because we've already done, but we need to normalize (to sum to 1) the single distributions before plotting.

```
# first method
p_pdf_1 = prod_pdf_1(x, dists)
# second method
p_pdf_2 = prod_pdf_2(pdfs)

# compare
for pdf in pdfs:
    # normalize PDF to sum to 1
    pdf /= pdf.sum()
    plt.plot(x, pdf)
plt.plot(x, p_pdf_1, label='prod 1', lw=5, color='C1')
plt.plot(x, p_pdf_2, label='prod 2', ls='--', color='k')
plt.legend();
```

[image]

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution, you'd better use a matrix, especially if you need to compute the conflation for a big number of distributions.

---

## update

A much more elegant solution is to simply do

```
# use computed PDFs and matrix
def conflate(pdfs):
    # numerator (product)
    conflation = pdfs.prod(axis=0)
    # normalize (divide by the integral)
    conflation /= conflation.sum()
    return conflation
```

and define PDFs as 2d-array (a `F`x`N` matrix, `F` distributions PDF and `N` length of discrete variable `x`)

```
# compute PDFs
pdfs = np.array([
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.0, 1.0),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.5, 1.5),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.2, 1.6),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.4, 1.3),
    sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.7, 1.5),
])
```

So we do

```
conflation = conflate(pdfs)

# compare
for i, pdf in enumerate(pdfs):
    # normalize PDF to sum to 1
    pdf /= pdf.sum()
    plt.plot(x, pdf, label=f'dist {i+1}')
plt.plot(x, conflation, label='conflation', ls='--', color='k')
plt.legend();
```

[image]

## update 2

Full code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def conflate(pdfs):
    """
    Compute conflation of given pdfs.
    
    [ARGS]
    - pdfs: PDFs numpy array of shape (n, x)
            where n is the number of PDFs
            and x is the variable space.
            
    [RETURN]
    A 1d-array of normalized conflated PDF.
    """
    # conflate
    conflation = pdfs.prod(axis=0)
    # normalize
    conflation /= conflation.sum()
    
    return conflation

# define x limits and size
lb = -10 
ub = 10 
size = 1000
# x linear space
x = np.linspace(lb, ub, size)

# define PDFs in x:
# these are Probability Density Functions
# evaluated in x defined linear space
pdf_1 = sps.norm.pdf(x, 2, 1)
pdf_2 = sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.5, 1.5) 
pdf_3 = sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.2, 1.6) 
pdf_4 = sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.4, 1.3) 
pdf_5 = sps.norm.pdf(x, 2.7, 1.5) 
# PDFs in (n, x) array
pdfs = np.array([pdf_1, pdf_2, pdf_3, pdf_4, pdf_5])
# compute PDFs conflation
conflated_pdf = conflate(pdfs)

# ..............................
#      >>> ========== <<<      .
# plot !!!_NORMALIZED_!!! PDFs .
#      >>> ========== <<<      .
# ..............................
for i, pdf in enumerate(pdfs):
    plt.plot(x, pdf/pdf.sum(), c=f'C{i}', label=f'PDF {i+1}', lw=1)
    # normalize =============
    #           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #           PDFs really do definitely need
    #           to be normalized, i.e. they have
    #           to sum to 1, because the cumulative
    #           probability needs to be 1 (100%)

# Plot conflated PDF
# NOTE: we don't need to normalize
# because it is already normalized
plt.plot(x, conflated_pdf, 
         'k--', label='Conflated PDF', lw=2)

# Plot options here
plt.xlabel("x") 
plt.ylabel("probability density") 
plt.title("Conflated PDF") 
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to use the Conflation method from the question, how can I get conflated PDF with the functions?

Comment: Thanks, I can see that with discrete. But, with an integral for continuous distribution, I think it is going to be different. I have been trying for days to solve this with integral but I am not sure how to overcome this problem.

Comment: You cannot have "continuous" distribution in python, as you define `x=np.linspace()` or `x=np.arange()`, variable `x` actually is discrete. So an integral (continuous) is a sum (discrete).